# run a function when insert file on sweetAlert

Tags: javascript, file

I'm changing an input file for a button that opens a new window using [sweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

```
        $('#btn-file').on('click', function (){
            (async () =>{
            let { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
                title: 'Select image',
                html: 'You can download a model for your work here',
                input: 'file',
                showCancelButton: true,
                inputAttributes: {
                    'accept': '.csv',
                    'aria-label': 'Upload your CSV file'
                }
            })
                if (file) {
                    const reader = new FileReader()
                    reader.onload = (e) => {

                      //CALL TO A FUNCTION
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
        })();
        });
```

I want to call my old function that it works correctly but is an input file

```
 $("#csv-file").change(handleFileSelect);

        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var file = evt.target.files[0];
            Papa.parse(file, {
         //rest of my code....
```

I want to call to handleFileSelect, actually, that function runs when the input file has changes, I want to run with my sweetAlert

how can I do?

if I just only call to `handleFileSelect();` I get this error

create:335 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

**Update to louys answer:**

my `Papa.parse(file)` is not working, in the console.log for file I get this

`console.log(file);` **when all is working**

```
File {name: "task import.csv", lastModified: 1613002044713, lastModifiedDate: Wed Feb 10 2021 20:07:24 GMT-0400 (hora de Bolivia), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 96, …}
lastModified: 1613002044713
lastModifiedDate: Wed Feb 10 2021 20:07:24 GMT-0400 (hora de Bolivia) {}
name: "task import.csv"
size: 96
type: ""
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

`console.log(file);` **when I use the solution**

```
data:application/octet-stream;base64,R29vZ2xlIFBsYWNlIFVSTCxCdXNpbmVzcyBUeXBlDQpodHRwOi8vd3d3LnJlc3RhdXJhbnQuY29tLFJlc3RhdXJhbnQNCmh0dHA6Ly93d3cuaG90ZWwuY29tLEhvdGVs
```

If I download that file link and put a .csv extension, the file is correct, but incompatible with [Papa.parse](https://www.papaparse.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a FileReader here. If there is a `file`... Pass it to your function.

```
$('#btn-file').on('click', function (){
  (async () =>{
    let { value: file } = await Swal.fire({
      title: 'Select image',
      html: 'You can download a model for your work here',
      input: 'file',
      showCancelButton: true,
      inputAttributes: {
        'accept': '.csv',
        'aria-label': 'Upload your CSV file'
      }
    })
    if (file) {
      
      //CALL TO A FUNCTION
      handleFileSelect(file);  // Try passing the file result directly
        
  })();
});

function handleFileSelect(file) {

  // Remove this... The file was passed as argument
  //var file = evt.target.files[0];
  
  //rest of my code....
```

Comment: Thank for the follow up with the edit! But if you fixed it passing `file` to your function, that means you don't event need a `FileReader` instance. lolll